# python 要素の値→(行,列):要素の値 への変更の仕方

Tags: python, python3, numpy

以下のような辞書を作りたいです.

`要素の値` → `(行,列):要素の値` に変更し, 出力するプログラムを作りたいです.
どのようにプログラムを組めばできますか？

**目的の辞書:**

```
 c={
   (1,1):2,(1,2):3,(1,3):3,(1,4):5,
   (2,1):2,(2,2):3,(2,3):3,(2,4):5,
   (3,1):2,(3,2):3,(3,3):3,(3,4):5,
   (4,1):2,(4,2):3,(4,3):3,(4,4):5,
   (5,1):2,(5,2):3,(5,3):3,(5,4):5,
    }
```

**元となる配列:**

```
c=[
 [2.  3.  3.  5.]
 [2.  3.  3.  5.]
 [2.  3.  3.  5.]
 [2.  3.  3.  5.]
 [2.  3.  3.  5.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

愚直な方法です。

```py
a = [
    [2,  3,  3,  5],
    [2,  3,  3,  5],
    [2,  3,  3,  5],
    [2,  3,  3,  5],
    [2,  3,  3,  5],
]

c = {}

for i, row in enumerate(a):
    for j, element in enumerate(row):
        c[(i + 1, j + 1)] = element

print(c)
```

```
{(1, 1): 2, (1, 2): 3, (1, 3): 3, (1, 4): 5, (2, 1): 2, (2, 2): 3, (2, 3): 3, (2, 4): 5, (3, 1): 2, (3, 2): 3, (3, 3): 3, (3, 4): 5, (4, 1): 2, (4, 2): 3, (4, 3): 3, (4, 4): 5, (5, 1): 2, (5, 2): 3, (5, 3): 3, (5, 4): 5}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげで自分の作りたいプログラムが完成しました

Answer (score 0):

Dict comprehension + `itertools.product`.

```
from itertools import product

c = [
  [2,  3,  3,  5],
  [2,  3,  3,  5],
  [2,  3,  3,  5],
  [2,  3,  3,  5],
  [2,  3,  3,  5],
]

c = {(i+1, j+1): c[i][j] for i, j in product(range(len(c)), range(len(c[0])))}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(c)

#
{
  (1, 1): 2, (1, 2): 3, (1, 3): 3, (1, 4): 5,
  (2, 1): 2, (2, 2): 3, (2, 3): 3, (2, 4): 5,
  (3, 1): 2, (3, 2): 3, (3, 3): 3, (3, 4): 5,
  (4, 1): 2, (4, 2): 3, (4, 3): 3, (4, 4): 5,
  (5, 1): 2, (5, 2): 3, (5, 3): 3, (5, 4): 5
}
```